# check profile in Opportunity Before update

Tags: apex

I have a requirement, where I have to write an `Opportunity` Trigger.

We have a Custom Object : `CheckStageConfig__c`. It has 3 fields : `From_Deal_Stage__c`(picklist) , `To_Deal_Stage__c`(picklist) and `Valid_profile__c`(MultiPicklist).

And ofcourse we have Opportunity Object. We are working with it's 1 field: `Stage`(picklist).

Requirement is : when we are changing `opportunity's` `stage` field from A to B, then code will check , do we have any entry in our custom object (`CheckStageConfig__c`). 
That is `From_Deal_Stage__c` value should be A and `To_Deal_Stage__c` value should be B. If yes,  then it will check what are all profile entries we have in `Valid_profile__c`.

If logged in user's profile is one of entry in `Valid_profile__c`, then we can update the record. else it will throw some custom message.

This is what I have done :

**Class :**

```
public static void validateOppDealStageChange(List<Opportunity> newList, Map<Id, Opportunity> oldMap) {

       Set<String> oldStageSet = new Set<String>();
       Set<String> newStageSet = new Set<String>();
       List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();      

       for(Opportunity opp : newList) {           
          Opportunity oldOpp = null;

          if(oldMap != null && oldMap.get(opp.id) != null) {
            oldOpp = oldMap.get(opp.id);            
          } 

          if(oldOpp != null && opp.StageName == oldOpp.StageName) {
            continue;
          } 

          oldStageSet.add(oldOpp.StageName);
          newStageSet.add(opp.StageName);
          oppList.add(opp);


        String ProfileName = [select Name from profile where id = :userinfo.getProfileId()].Name;
        system.debug('DEBUG **ProfileName:- '+ProfileName);

        Map<String, CheckStageConfig__c> ostMap = new Map<String, CheckStageConfig__c>();
        for(CheckStageConfig__c ost : [select From_Deal_Stage__c, 
                                                             To_Deal_Stage__c,
                                                             Valid_profile__c 
                                                        from CheckStageConfig__c
                                                        where From_Deal_Stage__c IN :oldStageSet
                                                        and To_Deal_Stage__c IN :newStageSet                                                       
                                                   ]) {

            ostMap.put(ost.Valid_profile__c, ost);

        }
        system.debug('ostMap:-'+ostMap);

        if(ostMap == null || ostMap.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }                                                            

    } 
}
```

I am able to fetch the qualified record, but problem is, how I will check if current profile is one of the profile in `Valid_profile__c`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a map try doing this:

```
Set<String> tmp = New Set<String>();
for(CheckStageConfig__c ost : [select From_Deal_Stage__c, 
                                                             To_Deal_Stage__c,
                                                             Valid_profile__c 
                                                        from CheckStageConfig__c
                                                        where From_Deal_Stage__c IN :oldStageSet
                                                        and To_Deal_Stage__c IN :newStageSet                                                       
                                                   ]) {



                tmp.addAll(ost.Valid_Profile__c != null ? ost.valid_Profile__c.split(';') : New String[]{});


        }
```

then you can check for the profile name by using `tmp.contains()`